# Why I am not able to build tree on JS function call using JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jstree

http://jsfiddle.net/2kwkh2uL/5498/

This is a sample code I am trying, to build a jsTree on a javascript function call but for some reason it's not doing it.

If I load it normally it build tree without any issue.
Can anyone please let me know what's wrong.

```js
function build_tree(tree_data) {
  $('#container').jstree({
    'core': {
      'data': tree_data
    }
  });
}


$("#gen_tree").click(function() {
  var tree_data = "[{ 'id' : 'cases_root', 'parent' : '#', 'text' : 'Cases [0,1,2]', 'case_id' : '0' },{ 'id' : 'my_cases', 'parent' : 'cases_root', 'text' : 'My Cases', 'case_id' : '0' },{ 'id' : 'active', 'parent' : 'my_cases', 'text' : 'active [0,1,2]', 'case_id' : '0' },{ 'id' : '2', 'parent' : 'active', 'text' : 'AXA Investment Managers [0,1,0]', 'case_id' : '0' },{ 'id' : '107157', 'parent' : '2', 'text' : 'Miani, Antonio [13]', 'case_id' : '107157' },{ 'id' : '98', 'parent' : 'active', 'text' : 'Graff Diamonds [0,0,1]', 'case_id' : '0' },{ 'id' : '106560', 'parent' : '98', 'text' : 'HEE JIN, Gong [18]', 'case_id' : '106560' },{ 'id' : '84', 'parent' : 'active', 'text' : 'Optiver Services BV [0,0,1]', 'case_id' : '0' },{ 'id' : '106608', 'parent' : '84', 'text' : 'SAVILUOTO, Antti [24]', 'case_id' : '106608' },]";
  build_tree(tree_data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://static.jstree.com/latest/assets/dist/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://static.jstree.com/latest/assets/dist/jstree.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<input id='gen_tree' type='button' value='Generate Tree' />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is because you're giving the `data` as a string, however it's not valid JSON, and hence cannot be deserialised by the jsTree library.

To fix the problem either correct the JSON format, or even easier, provide the data as an object. Try this:

```js
function build_tree(tree_data) {
  $('#container').jstree({
    'core': {
      'data': tree_data
    }
  });
}

$("#gen_tree").click(function() {
  var tree_data = [{
    'id': 'cases_root',
    'parent': '#',
    'text': 'Cases [0,1,2]',
    'case_id': '0'
  }, {
    'id': 'my_cases',
    'parent': 'cases_root',
    'text': 'My Cases',
    'case_id': '0'
  }, {
    'id': 'active',
    'parent': 'my_cases',
    'text': 'active [0,1,2]',
    'case_id': '0'
  }, {
    'id': '2',
    'parent': 'active',
    'text': 'AXA Investment Managers [0,1,0]',
    'case_id': '0'
  }, {
    'id': '107157',
    'parent': '2',
    'text': 'Miani, Antonio [13]',
    'case_id': '107157'
  }, {
    'id': '98',
    'parent': 'active',
    'text': 'Graff Diamonds [0,0,1]',
    'case_id': '0'
  }, {
    'id': '106560',
    'parent': '98',
    'text': 'HEE JIN, Gong [18]',
    'case_id': '106560'
  }, {
    'id': '84',
    'parent': 'active',
    'text': 'Optiver Services BV [0,0,1]',
    'case_id': '0'
  }, {
    'id': '106608',
    'parent': '84',
    'text': 'SAVILUOTO, Antti [24]',
    'case_id': '106608'
  }];
  build_tree(tree_data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://static.jstree.com/latest/assets/dist/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://static.jstree.com/latest/assets/dist/jstree.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<input id='gen_tree' type='button' value='Generate Tree' />
```

Comment: How do I convert this string to an object. Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: In this case all you need to do is remove the double quote characters (`"`) around it